# Condition Number of Rectangular Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, svd, condition-number

The 2-norm condition number can be easily extended to rectangular matrices. I'm wondering if the inequality for the product of matrices still holds in that case, i.e.,

$\operatorname{cond}(AB) \leq \operatorname{cond}(A)\operatorname{cond}(B)$

Comment: Yes, this is still true for rectangular matrices both in the spectral norm and in other norms.   It's a good exercise so I won't ruin the challenge for you.  A hint would be start by considering the definition of $\mathrm{cond}(A)$ that you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I figured out the answer to my question.

Suppose the SVD of $A = U \Sigma V^\ast$  (where $V^\ast$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix $V$). Noting the fact that the unitary transformations $U$ and $V$ preserve the 2-norm, $\|Ax\|_{2}$ for any unit vector $x$ can be written as

\begin{align*}
\frac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{2}} = \|Ax\|_{2}
&= \|U \Sigma V^\ast x\|_{2} \\
&= \| \Sigma V^\ast x\|_{2} \\
&= \| V^\ast \Sigma x\|_{2} \\ 
&= \|\Sigma x\|_{2}
\end{align*}

Hence $\|Bx\|_{2} \leq \sigma_\max(B)$ and $\|Bx\|_{2} \geq \sigma_\min(B)$.

For $y = Bx$,

\begin{equation*}
\|ABx\|_{2} = \|Ay\|_{2} \leq \sigma_\text{max}(A) \|y\|_{2} \leq \sigma_\max(A) \sigma_\max(B)
\end{equation*}

Similarly,

\begin{equation*}
\|ABx\|_{2} = \|Ay\|_{2} \geq \sigma_\min(A) \|y\|_{2} \geq \sigma_\min(A) \sigma_\min(B)
\end{equation*}

Since the above statements are true for all $x$, they are true both for the minimum and maximum. Thus, 
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_\max(AB) = \max \|ABx\|_{2} \leq \sigma_\max(A) \sigma_\max(B)
\end{equation*}

and
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_\min(AB) = \min \|ABx\|_{2} \geq \sigma_\min(A) \sigma_\min(B)
\end{equation*}

On dividing the above two equations, we obtain 
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{cond}_{2}(AB) \leq \operatorname{cond}_{2}(A) \operatorname{cond}_{2}(B)
\end{equation*}

Comment: You can accept your own answer.